# Svelte derived store returns incorrect value

Tags: svelte, svelte-store

I have a problem with derived store, which somehow returns an empty result even tho in the store is 1 record. The derived store depends on 2 writable stores: `assignedAgentsIds` (array of agent ids) and `agents` (map of agent entity). If I use both stores directly in a component, it works just fine, but when I use them in a derived store and try to combine them, I'm always getting empty array.

Here is my store code:

```js
const createAssignedAgentsStore = () => {
    const assignedAgentIds = writable<string[]>([])
    const { subscribe, set, update } = assignedAgentIds

    const setAssignedAgentIds = (agentIds: string[]) => {
        set(agentIds)
    }

    const addAssignedAgentId = (agentId: string) => {
        update((agentIds) => [...agentIds, agentId])
    }

    return {
        subscribe,
        setAssignedAgentIds,
        addAssignedAgentId,
    }
}

export const assignedAgentIds = createAssignedAgentsStore()

export const assignedAgents = derived([assignedAgentIds, agents], ([$assignedAgentIds, $agents]): Agent[] => {
    const assignedAgentsArr: Agent[] = []

    for (const agentId of $assignedAgentIds) {
        const agent = $agents[agentId]
        if (agent) assignedAgentsArr.push(agent)
    }

    return assignedAgentsArr
})
```

I tried to debug both `$assignedAgentIds` and `$agents` inside derived store, it has correct values and if there is 1 id in `assignedAgentsIds` and 1 record with the same id in `agents` map, still when I use `$assignedAgents` store in component, I get empty array instead of an array with 1 entity.

## Edit

In Svelte component, I had this code to show correct type of agents which was also using `assignedAgents` store:

```js
let headerAgents: Agent[] = []

$: {
    let agentsArray = Object.values($agents)
    if ($assignedAgents.length > 0) {
        agentsArray = $assignedAgents
    }

    headerAgents = agentsArray.splice(0, 3)
}
```

Comment: The derived store function could be written as: `([$ids, $agents]) => $ids.map(id => $agents[id]).filter(x => x)`

Comment: Is this a string/number problem? Are both `assignedAgentIds <string[]>` and the keys of `$agents` strings?

Comment: @Corrl Both are strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was passing reference to the `assignedAgents` store in component and mutating the store with `splice` function. Solution is to not mutate store by using `slice` function.

This is code that works:

```js
let headerAgents: Agent[] = []

$: {
    let agentsArray = Object.values($agents)
    if ($assignedAgents.length > 0) {
        agentsArray = $assignedAgents
    }

    headerAgents = agentsArray.slice(0, 3)
}
```

Comment: This question should either be deleted because as it is, this will be pretty useless to anyone else, or the question should be updated to show the faulty code and the answer should demonstrate how exactly to fix it.

Comment: True, I added faulty code and way how to fix it. Hope it can help someone.

Answer (score 1):

The code looked fine to me, so I just tried to run it and it worked. At least when the `agents` store is correctly in scope. Though it will throw if it isn't.

Full example:

```html
<script>
    import { writable, derived } from 'svelte/store';

    const createAssignedAgentsStore = () => {
        const assignedAgentIds = writable([])
        const { subscribe, set, update } = assignedAgentIds

        const setAssignedAgentIds = (agentIds) => {
            set(agentIds)
        }

        const addAssignedAgentId = (agentId) => {
            update((agentIds) => [...agentIds, agentId])
        }

        return {
            subscribe,
            setAssignedAgentIds,
            addAssignedAgentId,
        }
    }

    const assignedAgentIds = createAssignedAgentsStore()
    const agents = writable({
        0: 'Joe',
        1: 'Jane',
        2: 'Steve',
    });

    const assignedAgents = derived(
        [assignedAgentIds, agents],
        ([$assignedAgentIds, $agents]) => {
            const assignedAgentsArr = []

            for (const agentId of $assignedAgentIds)
            {
                const agent = $agents[agentId]
                if (agent) assignedAgentsArr.push(agent)
            }

            return assignedAgentsArr
        }
    )

    assignedAgentIds.setAssignedAgentIds([1, 2]);
</script>

{#each $assignedAgents as agent}
    <p>{agent}</p>
{/each}
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/58a01f6e65964029b596dda658c3d9c6?version=3.48.0)

I suspect the issue is elsewhere.

Comment: Just guessing, but could there be some sync issue between stores if I call set fn of both input stores too quickly after each other? That somehow derived store doesn't get notified about all changes?

Comment: I found strange, that if I put console.log into derived store, I see only 1 output in console, but both of input stores were changed, so I would expect 2 outputs in console. Maybe it's batching the changes?

Comment: Svelte works via invalidation followed by an update to the UI after the event loop. You can check the compiled Svelte output to find these `$$invalidate` calls. The next time the UI updates all locations where invalidated data is used are updated accordingly. The function of the derived store should be called multiple times if you change both stores, while the UI only updates once. Maybe you are overwriting one of the stores accidentally instead of setting it or something like that? (Like reassigning a `writable` to `agents` instead of using `set`, `update` or `$agents = ...`.)

Comment: thank you for the direction to solve this issue. I was accidentally mutating `assignedAgents` store in component with splice function.